# Bash - Find files from a specific directory

Tags: bash, shell, github-actions, glob

I am new to bash (but not to programming). I have a bash script that looks for all `.txt` files in a project

```
for i in `find . -name "*.txt"`;
do

 basename= "${i}"
 cp ${basename} ./dest
done
```

However, I would like to get the .txt files only from a specific sub directory. For e.g this is my project structure:

```
project/
├── controllers/
│   ├── a/
│   │   ├── src/
│   │   │   ├── xxx
│   │   │   └── xxx
│   │   └── files/
│   │       ├── abc.txt
│   │       └── xxxx
│   └── b/
│       ├── src/
│       │   ├── xxx
│       │   └── xxx
│       └── files/
│           ├── abcd.txt
│           └── xxxx
├── lib
└── tests
```

I would like to get `.txt` files only from `controllers/a/files` and `controllers/b/files`. I tried replacing `find . -name "*.txt"` with `find ./controllers/*/files/*txt`, it works fine, but errors out on GitHub actions with `No such file or directory found`. So I'm looking for a more robust way of finding `.txt` files from the subdirectory without having to hardcode the path in the for loop. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *brace expansion* for the search directory, e.g.

```bash
find ./project/controllers/{a,b} -type f -name "*.txt"
```

To select file only below `./project/controllers/a` and `./project/controllers/b`

Additionally, your use of `basename` would no longer be needed in your script (and cure the error with the `' '` (space) to the right of the `'='` sign. Traditionally in bash, you will use *process substitution* to feed a `while` loop rather than using a `for` loop, e.g.

```bash
while read -r fname; do
  # basename="${fname}"     # note! no ' ' on either side of =
  cp -ua "$fname" ./dest
done < <(find ./project/controllers/{a,b} -type f -name "*.txt")
```

---

**Edit Based On Comment of Many Paths**

If you have many `controllers` not just `a` and `b`, then using the `-path` option instead of the `-name` options can provide a solution, e.g.

```bash
find . -path "./project/controllers/*/files/*.txt" -type f
```

would select any `".txt"` files below any directory below `controllers` that contains a `files` directory.

Comment: So the controllers in the example have been reduced for readability sake. in reality, there are more than 10 controllers. so I don't think adding all the names to the subdirectory would look good. also, like I mentioned, `find ./controllers/*/files/*txt` works fine on local, but it errors on GitHub actions since it cannot look for the project at runtime

Comment: Well, that is a little different from `a` and `b`, but I understand the question. How are you getting the shell on github? You have direct access to the large project directory there, or a cloned repository on your local machine? Also on the actual shell you are using can you do an `echo $SHELL` to make sure it is bash (you may already know, but I just want to be clear we don't have a POSIX/bash issue at work too)

Comment: this is great, thanks for the answer. but again it comes down to adding all the controllers part of the controllers sub dir. since there are 10+ child dirs in controllers, I would have to add them to the brace {a,b,c,d,.....}. and I would have to do it every time a new controller is added. is there a way of not having to do this? its a cloned repo on my machine. and yes confirming it is bash

Comment: thanks for the answer that addresses the comment on many paths. is there a way to add a `if` block to my original script, where it would check if the base name starts with `'./controllers'`, it would execute the rest of the script?

Comment: Sure, `if [[ $fname =~ "./controllers" ]]; then ## do something with $fname; done` (note `=~` is a bash-only feature -- a bashism) Also note, you can unquote the right-hand side to have it treated as an extended regex which allows you to also provide an anchor, e.g. `[[ $fname =~ ^[.]/controllers ]]`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me what you need is a simple `cp` command,

```
cp project/controllers/*/files/*.txt ./dest/
```

if you want to copy only the files with `.txt` extension under the directory `files` (but not in its subdirectories, if any)

Answer (score 0):

`find ./controllers/*/files/*txt` does not really make sense to me, as it means that `find` should start at a directory tree matching this name, but you don't have a directory with a name ending in `txt`.

You can do a

```
find controllers -prune src -name "*.txt"
```

to exclude txt files in the src directories. Another possibility would be to do

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in controllers/*/files/*.txt
do
  ...
done
```